# Allow terminal servers users to search within file contents

Tags: windows, search, windows-server-2008, search-indexing

Ok, so we have this customer who wants to search within .docx and .doc files. They work on three Citrix XenApp/XenDesktop servers and all the .doc and .docx files are stored on a seperate fileserver. Everything is 2008 R2.

I have installed the Indexing Service on the fileserver and added the folder with Word files. I've also installed the Office 2010 filter pack. It created an index after a few minutes and all looks fine.

However, when I try to search for a word which is inside on of the .docx/.doc files nothing comes up. Not on the fileserver and not on the Citrix servers.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Indexing Service is to support legacy clients and applications that are not compatible with the newer Windows Search Service.

Newer clients and servers will support and use Windows Search Service. It will also work with Windows XP clients that have Windows Desktop Search installed.

[image]

From the help:

> Which indexing solution should I install?
>
> You should install Windows
> Search Service, unless you have a customized or non-Microsoft
> application that requires you to run the legacy Indexing Service on
> your server. Windows Search Service offers several enhancements over
> Indexing Service, especially in the areas of extensibility, usability,
> and performance.
>
> If you have applications that require Indexing Service, we recommend
> that you upgrade them to be compatible with Windows Search Service

.

Comment: Cheers! It's literally above the 2003 checkbox and I still missed it :-|